# Can we use nant to build .sln files in C#?

Tags: c#, nant

Can we use nant to build .sln files in C#?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest approach in my experience is to use NAnt to call MSBuild, and get MSBuild to build the solution file itself. See my [Protocol Buffers build file](http://github.com/jskeet/dotnet-protobufs/blob/8e1b456365efe0b082ea79d8221297879d1a155c/ProtocolBuffers.build) as an example.

I use [NAntContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/) which has an `msbuild` task:

```
<property name="nantcontrib-dir"
   value="${path::combine(nant::get-base-directory(), '../../NAntContrib')}"
   overwrite="false" />

<loadtasks assembly=
    "${path::combine(nantcontrib-dir, 'bin/NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll')}" 
 />  

...

<target name="build"
        description="Builds all C# code">
  <msbuild project="${src}/ProtocolBuffers.sln">
    <property name="Configuration"
              value="${build-configuration}" />
  </msbuild>
</target>
```

Comment: Stop answering the same as I'm thinking all the time, before me. At least 10k of your rep should have been mine! :P

Comment: @configurator: You've been Skeeted!

Comment: Hmm I believe that the link to your own project is broken... 

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn: Strangely enough, it's quite hard to keep 35,000 answers all up-to-date... (It's been many years since I used NAnt at all.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Oh, _only_ 35,000? I thought it was far more than that...  heh! Seriously, thanks for all your answers — as well as for all those links. I just happen to be in the middle of hacking & slashing a decade-old project in the hope to resurrect it, ready for the 2020s, and I'm searching for a bit of information on how things _used_ to be, and how old code can be dragged, kicking and screaming, into the new decade. Your own answer was, by far, the most intriguing; it's a pity that the original file you had linked there is gone, though.

Answer (score 3):

[msbuild](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc4/help/tasks/msbuild.html) task that can either just build your solution or execute an entire msbuild script:

```
<target name="compile">
       <msbuild project="xxx.sln">
              <arg value="/property:Configuration=release" />                                  
              <arg value="/t:Rebuild" />
       </msbuild>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke `msbuild` as a nant task.

Answer (score 2):

[solution](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/solution.html) task might help.

Comment: Read under Note: Right now, only Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2002 and 2003 solutions and projects are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution task although that's not been supporting VS2008 solutions outside of the Beta versions of nant.  It's coming though.